# Understanding umask

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, permissions

I have the following task:

What are the rights if you create a file file1 and a directory dir1 and used `umask 026` before? Now use `umask 233` and perform the following:

```
cat file1 > file2  
mv file1 file3  
mkdir dir2
```

What rights do the files file2,file2 and file3 have?
The solution is:

```
file1: 640  
dir1: 751  
file2: 444  
file3: 640  
dir2: 544
```

Isn't `umask 233` that the user can write, group can write and execute, rest can write and execute as well?

Comment: For files the formula is `0666 & ~umask`, and for directories it's `0777 & ~umask`. What exactly do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`umask` generally comes into picture when any new file or new directory is created with a specific user.
if a file has `666` permissions, it grants `read and write` permission to everyone. Similarly a directory with `777` permissions, grants `read, write, and execute` permission to everyone.

`umask 000` --> provides 666 permission to all the newly created files , and it provides 777 permission to all the newly created directories.

The octal umasks are calculated via the bitwise AND of the unary complement of the argument using bitwise NOT.

**Formula for files:**

1. *for files:*

`666 - (umask value) eg:  for umask of 022, the permission of a newly created file will be: 666 - 022 = 644 ,i.e -rw-r-r`

2. *for directories:*

`777 - (umask value) eg: for a umask of 022, the permission of a newly created directory will be 777 - 022 = 755, i.e drwxr-xr-x`

Here's a comprehensive list of the umask values and their corresponding permissions for files and directories: https://www.linuxtrainingacademy.com/all-umasks/

from your example, `file1` and `dir1` were created with `umask 026` , so it has the permission as : `640`(666 - 026) and `751`(777 - 026) respectively... whereas the `file2` and `dir2` were created with `umask 233` , so it has the permisisons as `444` and `544` respectively.